# Tanist votes are never saved except mine: they are empty when I load the game

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I have Tanistry succession method, and I've noticed that every time I load the game, only my vote is counted, and all my vassals vote again in a few days.

Is this a known bug, and is there a known workaround? If I just let it be, does it matter? Unless I happen to die before they did cast their votes, I don't see how this could cause problems, *but since I'm a bit new to this game, I'd better ask*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug. I believe it has been observed in elective as well. The fix is pretty much to not die within a week of starting up the game. Alternatively, TRY to die during the first three days and laugh about your good fortune that only your vote mattered in deciding your heir.